# Prevent animation on Loading React Component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-animations

Basically, I have a component with some animation, but I want to show them only when the user resize the page in a certain breakpoint (if the width is <800px, then I rearrange the divs, and in that case I want to show the animation).

I manage to do that, but the problem is that, when I first load the page, the animations will start, when I wouldn't show them.

Hope I've been clear enough

**EDIT:** have this divs in the render() function of 'Test' Component, where 'main-content' it's flex, the first two divs are in the first row each with 50% of width, and the third inside div it's in the second row with 100% width.

```
<div className="main-content">
    <div className="content-box admin-setting-container">
    </div>

    <div className="content-box change-password-container">
    </div>

    <div className="content-box organization-setting-container">
    </div>
</div>
```

In the .css file I have this code:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .change-password-container, .organization-setting-container {
        animation: fadeDown 0.5s ease-out;
    }
}

@keyframes fadeDown {
    0% {
        opacity: 0.01;
        transform: translateX(-25%);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}
```

So that, when the width of window became <1000, I'll have three row, one for each inside divs. It works, but the problem is that, if I open the page while the width it's already <1000, the animation will still perform, even if I would prevent them.

One thing that I tried was to have the div 'main-content' with a special class 'preload', and then remove that class once the component was Mount. The CSS class preload would prevent the animation. Let me show you the code.

```
/* IN REACT COMPONENT FILE */
componentDidMount() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("preload")[0].classList.remove("preload");
}
... <div className="main-content preload"> ... </div> ...

/*IN CSS FILE */
.preload * {
     animation-duration: 0s !important;
     -webkit-animation-duration: 0s !important;
 }
```

Comment: You based your animation on the resize event? please show us you'r code so we will be able to see what went wrong.

Comment: Are you missing a closing brace on the media or is it just missing because of the copy?

Comment: Was because of the copy, sorry!
@MatanBobi that's actually all the code (expect like class Test extends ...).. There's no event resize listener here, it's all done by the CSS media query.. When the size of the screen became less than 1000, the css loaded for each container change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, now I see what your'e talking about.
The thing is you are trying to animate only when you're resizing but the media query happens every time you'r width is lower than 1000px.

IMO you should add a class for a resizing event.
I would build it this way:

```
  updateWidth() {
    if(window.innerWidth < 1000 && this.state.width > 1000 || window.innerWidth > 1000 && this.state.width < 1000) {
      this.setState({ width window.innerWidth });
    }
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.updateWidth);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.updateWidth);
  }
```

and in the component I would check if the width on the state is lower than 1000 and add the animate class. if it's bigger, remove the animate class.
Don't forget to bind the event listener handler in the constructor.

Comment: The fact is that even when I go from less than 1000 to more than 1000 I will have an animation (still have to write it, though)..
But I think I can arrange your idea: I could have a variable inside the state like "isResize" that is false. As long as it is false, the animation will not be reproduce, and, as soon as the user will resize the window, isResize will be set to true, so that the animation will be reproduced.. Sounds right?

Comment: definitely possible... just keep in mind to check that the width is correct so you won't make the animation on each resize. and maybe think of a debounce/throttle for that so you won't call setState too many times

Comment: Well, I think i don't need the check on the width.. Let me explain: once the div are loaded, the animation won't be fired.. So animations will be played only when going from <1000 and >1000.. I'm pretty sure 'bout that. Regarding the throttle, you are totally right: in another component I have the listener on resize event and I think the throttle it's a must.. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes you are right, if you keep you'r animation inside the media query.. No problem, glad I could help.. Please mark this as an answer for later on searches. @MatteoGesmundo

Answer (score -2):

Do you have a code spinet at all? It sounds like something is happening on the "componentDidMount" you could try the following.

```
componentDidMount = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: `componentDidMount` has no e since no event triggers it, it is a lifecycle method

Comment: Sorry, should have wrote it before. I've added some code. Hope it's enough to give you an idea to what I meant

Comment: it looks like you are calling a life cycle method "componentDidMount" and its running the animation every time.. every time your component mounts the animation is going to run